# Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I updated Gradle configuration to the latest Spring Cloud version and Spring version:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
    implementation 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.5.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    // Mapstruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    // Swagger
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But when I start the application I get:

```
10:11:27.970 [main] ERROR SpringApplication[reportFailure:843] - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at org.MerchantHubApplication.main(MerchantHubApplication.java:18)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

application.yml configuration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
```

Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: are you make ```@enableEurekaClient``` inside main method  and are you run registry service befour this project

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Answer (score 7):

Some times it happens from of **JRE version**:

May your compile-time JDK version and Runtime JDK version be different.

Like: **Compile-time JDK 11** and **Runtime JDK 17**.

**Runtime JRE will be same as Compile-time.**

Comment: How to check compiler time jdk version and runtime jdk version in eclipse?

Comment: For you compile file you can check this way: 
=>javap -verbose SimpleClsFile.class | findstr "major"

You know your current runtime jre version right ! you can find it from 
https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/

Answer (score 1):

you must added it in Gradle config i dont now how you can add like it inside your Gradle configuration but i have the same problem with maven project i added this inside pom.xml with

when added it without `<dependencyManagement>` i see same your problem

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but after added  below  config i run project and registry in eureka without any problem

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

i think this solution help you to solution your problem but you must convert it from maven to Gradle

Comment: He already have set all this in his gradle file

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the version `2.2.5.RELEASE` caused the error.
Therefore, I try to change it into `3.1.3` like below, then it runs without any problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with running my project. If you are working on IntellijIDE you need to check: **File -> Project Structure -> Project**: here you need to check your **SDK** and **Language level** to be the same as  in your pom file

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue come from the version of your spring could vs your spring boot version try to update both to the following version

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.10-SNAPSHOT'


set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.5")
```

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency from client side

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

- also you might face this issue in spring boot version 3X

[image]